# Não exibir valor null (01/01/0001) de um Datetime em uma DataGridView

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

Minha `DataGridView` possui alguns campos `DateTime` com valor `null` (01/01/0001). Como faço para não exibir esses valores, deixando o campo em branco?

Atualmente:

[image: Atualmente:]

Como eu gostaria que ficasse:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou utilizando `WindowsForm`, **C#** e **.Net Framework 3.5**. 
Lembrando que utilizo `databinding` na minha `DataGridView`.

Comment: Voce utiliza colunas predefinidas do datagriview ou deixa que ele gera as colunas automaticamente?... caso for predefinido... e so editar a coluna... tem uma SUB-propriedade nela chamada NullValue... tente colocar null ou 01/01/0001

Comment: Você já tentou colocar essa coluna no seu BD como não obrigatória e usar o tipo `DateTime?` ao invés de `DateTime`? A diferença é que o primeiro aceita valores nulos diferentemente do segundo.

Answer (score 3):

Resposta dada antes de o OP indicar que está usando ***WindowsForms***.

**Solução para WPF.**

Utilize um ***ValueConverter*** para converter *DateTime* em *string*.
Ao fazer a conversão se o valor do *DateTime* é `DateTime.MinValue` retorna-se `string.Empty;` caso contrário retorna-se `dateTime.ToString()`

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(DateTime), typeof(string))]
public class DateTimeToString : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is DateTime)
        {
            var dateTime = (DateTime)value;
            if (dateTime == DateTime.MinValue)
            {
                return string.Empty;
            }
            return dateTime.ToString();
        }
        throw new ArgumentException("value");
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is string)
        {
            var dateString = (string) value;
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(dateString))
            {
                return DateTime.MinValue;
            }
            return DateTime.Parse(dateString);
        }
        throw new ArgumentException("value");
    }
}
```

Para usar o *ValueConverter* deve primeiro declará-lo na secção `<Windos.Resources>` da sua *Window*.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:DateTimeToString x:Key="DateTimeToString" />
</Window.Resources>
```

Depois atribua-o ao atributo *Converter* do *Binding* da *DataGridTextColumn*

```
<DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Data" Binding="{Binding data, Converter={StaticResource DateTimeToString}" />
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:

Foi mal, não tinha visto que estava usando o databinding, nesse caso acho que a minha solução não se aplica, porém é válida para outros casos.

Você pode fazer algo do tipo:

```
if (data != DateTime.MinValue)
   tabela[indexColuna, indexLinha].Value = data;
```

ou

```
if (data.Year  != 0001)
   tabela[indexColuna, indexLinha].Value = data;
```

isso deve funcionar

Comment: Você pode verificar tbm se o `data.Year == 0001` e se for não definir o valor da célula.